# Hide/show particular element on click with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I have an HTML table with many rows in it and want to hide a row when the user clicks the delete button for that particular row. I'm having trouble doing it with Angular and the `ng-hide` directive.

Here's my (simplified) HTML code for just two rows:

```
   <tr ng-hide="isRowHidden">
     <td>Example template title</td>
     <td>
       <a href="#" ng-click="deleteTemplate(@template.id)">Delete template</a>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-hide="isRowHidden">
     <td>Another example template title</td>
     <td>
       <a href="#" ng-click="deleteTemplate(@template.id)">Delete template</a>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

And here is my Angular code (in CoffeeScript) thus far:

```
 $scope.deleteTemplate = (templateId) ->
    console.log "Deleting template id #{templateId}" 
    $scope.isRowHidden = true
```

I know that the last line is incorrect because it hides all rows instead of just one. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to model the data as an array with multiple isRowHidden values, then list the rows via ng-repeat:

http://jsfiddle.net/XqchD/ (uses JS, not coffee)

```
myApp = angular.module("myApp", [])

FieldCtrl = ($scope) ->
  $scope.data = fields: [
    value: "1F"
    isRowHidden: false
  ,
    value: "2F"
    isRowHidden: false
  ]
  $scope.deleteTemplate = (field) ->
    console.log field
    field.isRowHidden = true
```

HTML:

```
 <table ng-repeat="field in data.fields">
   <tr ng-hide="field.isRowHidden">
     <td>{{field.value}}</td>
     <td>
       <a href="#" href="#" ng-click="deleteTemplate(field)">Delete template</a>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: What would this look like in the controller?

Comment: Updated answer, hope it clarifies